# How do I subtract the smallest number from each integer in a list using a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, numbers

input:

```
5
30
50
10
70
65
```

5 is how many numbers follow after.

My code:

```
n = int(input())
list = []
i = 0
while len(list) < n:
    integer = int(input())
    list.append(integer)
    i = i + 1
    minList = min(list)
    integers = list[i - 1] - minList
    print(integers)
```

I'm suppose to subtract the smallest number from the 5 integers.

The correct output:
20
40
0
60
55

My output:
0
20
0
60
55

I understand why my output is wrong since the smallest number is 20 until 10 is inputed, but I don't know how to correct it. I tried different ways, but none of them work. How do I subtract the smallest number from each integer?

Comment: Your indentation if off - currently all is below the while list - the code you use there makes no sense and would throw plenty of errors. Also: dont name your variables after built ins - the name `list` is already taken by the datastructure. Use `data`, `numbers` or call it `hugo` so you do not shadow said built ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all the input first, then find the minimum value and print the numbers.

```
n = int(input())
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < n:
    integer = int(input())
    numbers.append(integer)
smallest = min(numbers)
for number in numbers:
    print number - smallest
```

Comment: What is the purpose of i = 0?

Comment: It was copied from the original code and I forgot to remove it.  I'll remove it now.

Answer (score 0):

Get the inputs to a list. Take minimum of this list using `min()` and then subtract minimum value from each of the list elements:

```
n = int(input())                  # Read number of numbers
lst = []

for _ in range(n):
    lst.append(int(input()))      # Append to list

min_value = min(lst)              # Take the minimum number
final_lst = [abs(x-min_value) for x in lst]  # Subtract minimum from each number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size = int(input())
lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(size)]
m = min(lst)
res = [abs(n - m) for n in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a default puzzle for sites like Hackerrank ... take all the inputs , then perform your operations on all inputs. Do not meddle with data while still gathering inputs (unless it makes sense to do so).

A nice way of getting all the data is:

```
n = int(input())    # get how many inputs follow

# get n inputs, perform the int() conversion, store as list.
data = list(map(int, (input().strip() for _ in range(n))))

# calculate the min value
min_value = min(data)

# print all reduced values in order each on one line
print( *[x-min_value for x in data], sep = "\n")
# or comma seperated:
print( *[x-min_value for x in data], sep = ",")
```

Output:

```
# print with sep="\n"
20
40
0
60
55

# print with sep=","
20,40,0,60,55
```

Read the doku for [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), [min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and look at [Built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html): do not use those as names for your variables, neither use `list`,`dict`,`set`,`tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = list()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    l.append(int(input()))
xmin = min(l)
print(*[x - xmin for x in l])
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
5
30
50
10
70
65
20 40 0 60 55
```